# What does CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE affect, other than the compiler flag selection?

Tags: cmake, release-builds, debug-build

I [know](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables) that if if we set `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` (or `Debug` etc.), then the values of `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` will be appended to `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` respectively.

But is this the only effect of setting the build type? If not, what are the other effects?

Comment: Just as a quick note: You should avoid the CMake wiki, if possible, as it is fairly outdated and often not very accurate. The [official documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/) is a way better source of information (at least for CMake versions 3.0 and up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, build type affects on **many things**. Among them:

- [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html):

  Expression `$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:XXX>` will be expanded to `XXX` with CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE set to `Debug` and to nothing otherwise.

  Because *generator expressions* can be used in a number of commands, setting build type affects all commands which uses expressions dependent on build type.
- libraries added by `target_link_libraries` with *debug* keyword take an effect only in `Debug` build type.

  Similar to *optimized* keyword.

  (Implicitely, this uses generator expressions described above).
- Some properies of *IMPORTED* libraries.

  Properties like *IMPORTED_LOCATION* have [config-specific variants](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION_CONFIG.html), which are choosen dependent on configuration type.

  Often *IMPORTED* libraries are created as a result of `find_package()` call, so your project may be linked with 3d-party project in configuration-dependent manner.
- *CONFIGURATION*-specific part of [install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/install.html) command.

  Only those `CONFIGURATION <conf>` part are applies, which corresponds to active configuration.

---

*Multi-configuration* tools doesn't use `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable, but they still have a notion of the "build type". That build type is NOT known at *configuration* stage, when CMake parses `CMakeLists.txt`, it is set only when performing a **build** of the project. Nevertheless, this build type "retroactively" affects on all properties described above.

Also, with *multi-configuration* build tools selected build type is appended to the location of output artifacts, like executables and libraries (see e.g. description of [RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) target's property).

Comment: Not sure I understand the last paragraph. Afaik, the value of `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` should have no effect for multi-configuration generators. This is also what [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) states: *This variable is only meaningful to single-configuration generators*.

Comment: Can you expand a bit, perhaps with an example, on the different bullets?

Comment: I have edited description of the build type for multi-configuration tools. Hope things become clear now.